# C# array of variables

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
string A = "A";
string B = "B";

object[] O = { A, B };
O[0] = "C";
```

Where `A` will hold the value `"C"` in the end?

The code above will replace `O[0]` with `"C"`, but `A` remains unchanged.

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: It will end up taking you much more time to post this question and read the responses then to just copy/paste that into a compiler and find out for yourself.

Comment: @seth, I think the wording of the question indicates the user is aware that this will not work as he intends. The question is not whether this code works, it's more of what code will, if any.

Comment: I believe you guys are misunderstanding the question. The OP wants to know if it's possible to have something like that replace the value of `A`, not if/how the code works.

Comment: I have tried it already. O[0] holds the value "C" but A still holds the value "A".

Answer (score 12):

No - at least not in safe code.

When you create the array, it copies the *values* into the array. Changing the value in the array later won't change the value of the variable. There's no way of creating a sort of "ref array", where the array elements are shared with the variables. (As shown in Mark's answer, there are sometimes ways of doing this in unsafe code, but I'd really suggest staying away from that.)

Note, however, that if both the array and the variable refer to the same *mutable object* then mutating that object via either path will make a change which is visible via the other:

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder[] array = new StringBuilder[] { x };

array[0].Append("Foo");
Console.WriteLine(x); // Prints "Foo"
```

This is no different to any other assignment though - and note that in the code above, the `Append` call doesn't change the value of either `x` or the array element; it changes the data within the object that those values refer to.

Comment: @quantumSoup: Yes, within unsafe code - and *maybe* this would be possible here, but I'm not happy enough about the idea in general to look into it further...

Answer (score 1):

While the answer is no in the case of string, you can do this with value types:

```
class Program
{
  static unsafe void Main()
  {
    char A = 'A';
    char B = 'B';

    var O = new char*[] { &A, &B };

    *O[0] = 'C';

    System.Console.WriteLine(A + "," + B); // outputs C,B            
  }
}
```

Unsafe code is typically frowned upon in C#. So, while this kind of thing is possible, I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to convert your strings into objects with properties.
You can then Cast your array object on the specific key to this object type you created, and then you can set its property again.

This way you can change both what's in your array, as your original variable, therefor, it is similar to seeing it as an array with values by reference.

> ```
> public class stringObject
> {
>   private string name;
>   public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
> }
> ```

```
stringObject A = new stringObject();
A.Name = "A";
stringObject B = new stringObject();
B.Name = "B";

object[] O = { A, B };

//change the array at key 0, and also changing our original variable
stringObject C = O[0] as stringObject;
C.Name = "C";
```

The above code will not only change what is inside O[0], but it will also update what is inside your object A.

An example with a test to write to the console can be seen here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yt25hy

Comment: In case of interest, I made a second fiddle, similar, but with a method, so you can do it in 1 line & reuse this code and also added a constructor to the object class, this should make it a little easier to use.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VrjAFj